# Which is the best way to create Magento 2 Payment extension?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

I want to create a Magento 2 Payment extension. But the thing is **which is the best method to create a Payment extension out of below two methods.**

1. Magento 2 Payment Gateway API
2. Default Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Cc

Magento says `Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Cc` class is **depreciated in Magento 2.2.X** versions, but still, Authorize.Net direct payment is using it.

So, please help me to find out the best method.

Thanks

Comment: Magento 2 payment gateway API provides abstract payment gateway. I would recomme d to implement Magento 2 Payment Gateway API.

Comment: Can i get help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/302345/57334 @Meetanshi Thanks